# prevent Selenium WebDriver to exit after catching an exception

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using `Selenium Web Driver` to fill a simple form:

```
private WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

And the function:

```
public boolean fillDetailsInWeb(JsonElement data,String url){
        System.out.println("fill in-"+url);
        boolean result = false;
        try{
            driver.navigate().to(url);

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error in driver " + e.getMessage().toString());
            return result;
        }
        //web elements
        try{
            WebElement name_to_input = driver.findElement(By.id("ID1"));
            WebElement email_to_input =  driver.findElement(By.id("id2"));
            WebElement message_to_input = driver.findElement(By.id("ID3"));
        }catch(NoSuchElementException MSEE){
            MSEE.printStackTrace();
        }
        result = true;
        return result;
    }
```

I want the process to continue after catching `NoSuchElementException` and the program to go to the next site.
What is the right way to do so?

Comment: you could perhaps loop over them?

Comment: Are you testing this webpage/form, or are you just testing data downstream?

Comment: only this form. I will post the results later, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As title states, if you want to continue execution even if an unexpected exception occurs, you need to use **`The Finally Block`** as well along with **`Try...Catch...`** block.

From **[this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html)** link:

The finally block always executes when the try block exits. This ensures that the finally block is executed even if an unexpected exception occurs. But finally is useful for more than just exception handling — it allows the programmer to avoid having cleanup code accidentally bypassed by a return, continue, or break. Putting cleanup code in a finally block is always a good practice, even when no exceptions are anticipated.

So your Try Catch block with Finally would be:

```
...
try{
    driver.navigate().to(url);

}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Error in driver " + e.getMessage().toString());
    return result;
}
//web elements
try{
    WebElement name_to_input = driver.findElement(By.id("ID1"));
    WebElement email_to_input =  driver.findElement(By.id("id2"));
    WebElement message_to_input = driver.findElement(By.id("ID3"));
}catch(NoSuchElementException MSEE){
    MSEE.printStackTrace();

} finally {
    return result;
}
...
```

Comment: Works fine, but is that the proper way to this kind of execution?

Comment: Well, if you are filling the web forms by opening different URLs in a loop, than this would be your best bet. There are several different ways depending on the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Looping it will not continue to next step.

try to determine first which element is not present or make a verification every step for example:

```
    try{
        WebElement name_to_input = driver.findElement(By.id("ID1"));

    }catch(Exception MSEE){
        MSEE.printStackTrace();
    }
    try{
        WebElement name_to_input = driver.findElement(By.id("ID2"));

    }catch(Exception MSEE){
        MSEE.printStackTrace();
    }
```

or

```
String[] id = {"id1","id2"}

for(int c=0;c<2;c++)
   try{
        WebElement name_to_input = driver.findElement(By.id(id[c]));

    }catch(Exception MSEE){
        MSEE.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I change the NoSuchElementException to Exception only so that if the element is present but not visible. selenium still move to next step.

Im just new but hope this can help.